# Adding image and video file path to the custom table from the review frontend product view page

Tags: database, frontend, review, magento2.3.3

I have created a custom table for storing `review_id` (as **foreign key**),file_path and file_type(boolean 1 for image and 2 for video) as columns. i have to add the post values from the product review page from frontend.i have created the model, **resource** **model** and **collection** for that. i know that in

> core controller/product/post.php

has my post values in $data.

[image]

But I don't know how to add the custom image or video path to the database and the type.